# Converting pandas Column to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to convert a pandas column to datetime. This is my error message.

> ValueError: time data '01-JUN-17 00:00:00' does not match format
>   '%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%S' (match)

This is my code :

```
df['dayofservice'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['dayofservice'], format = '%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%S')
```

I have read this documentation to ensure my format is correct : https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

It's still not working for me.

Answer (score 4):

`pandas` is man/woman enough to parse this without a format field:

```
In[90]:
pd.to_datetime('01-JUN-17 00:00:00')

Out[90]: Timestamp('2017-06-01 00:00:00')
```

So this should work:

```
df['dayofservice'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['dayofservice'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `.` to `:` in times like:

```
df['dayofservice'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['dayofservice'], format = '%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S')
```